# SIAM LaTeX styling - marging width differences

Tags: margins

I am learning about SIAMs LaTeX styling: https://epubs.siam.org/journal-authors#macros

I enjoy their templates, but why is their right margin significantly larger than their top, left, and bottom margins? I want to use their template, but with equal margins.

Comment: journals are not usually printed in final form on A4 or US Letter paper so the "margin" of a draft mauscript is just an artifact of being printed on a "wrong" paper size.

Comment: Thanks, that essentially answers the question. Though, I am left with wanting equal margins. For example, I want equal margins on A4 size paper. I suppose I will have to find a different template?

Comment: if you are submitting to siam don't change the layout it will mess up their production, for your own use just add `geometry` package and specify whatever margins you want

Comment: Thanks, if you could put your original comment as an Answer I'll accept it so we may close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journals are not usually printed in final form on A4 or US Letter paper so the "margin" of a draft manuscript is just an artifact of being printed on a "wrong" paper size.